# Newbie to SQL I have run the the inner join query but result comes up with columns only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have run this query in adventureworks but the result is run successfully but i only get the columns instead of the data with columns how so?

```
select 
       a.BusinessEntityID,b.bonus,b.SalesLastYear 
from
       [Sales].[SalesPersonQuotaHistory] a

inner join
       [Sales].[SalesPerson] b
on    
       a.SalesQuota = b.SalesQuota
```

Comment: it means there is any matching rows between these 2 tables based on SalesQuota

Comment: is there data where SalesQuota in SalesPersonQuotaHistory equals SalesPerson?

Comment: Yes there is data but the first row has a null but the rest of the columns do have data.

Comment: but is there any matching values for SalesQuota in those 2 tables ?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Formatted text please, not images.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that instead of joining the tables on SalesQuota, you should be joining them on something else - An ID field, typically.

I don't have Adventureworks here, but judging from the names of the tables and the columns that you've provided, I would assume that there's a `SalesPersonID` field of some sort that actually connects a Salesperson's quota history to the Salesperson him/herself.

I would expect that you're looking for something closer to this:

```
SELECT 
        a.BusinessEntityID
       ,b.bonus
       ,b.SalesLastYear 
FROM [Sales].[SalesPersonQuotaHistory] a
INNER JOIN [Sales].[SalesPerson] b
    ON a.SalesPersonID = b.SalesPersonID
```

General Knowledge:

`INNER JOIN` means "Show me only entries (rows) that have a matching value on both sides of the condition." (i.e. The value in Table A matches the value in Table B).

So `ON a.SalesQuota = b.SalesQuota` means "Only where the value of SalesQuota in Table A matches the value of SalesQuota in Table B."

I'm not sure what the purpose of this query could be, since it is entirely possible that two salespeople have the same values in both tables, and then you would get duplicate rows (because the values of SalesQuota would match in both cases), or that the values wouldn't match at all, and then you wouldn't get any rows - I suspect that is what's happening to you.

Consider the conditions of what you're trying to join. Are you really trying to join quota amounts, or are you trying to retrieve quota information for specific salespeople? The answer should help guide your `JOIN` conditions.